# Google maps crash and memory use

Tags: android, google-maps, ionic3

Google maps native plugin ionic 3

Sometimes during normal google maps operations like adding markers in loop or clearing map, there is an application crash. There is no patter for the crash. And the error message is as one bellow:

**java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -1
        at plugin.google.maps.PluginMarker$3.run(PluginMarker.java:149)**

Could someone tell me what does it mean, cause I think that it is connected with google maps native plugin error.

Sometimes it breaks during normal map use, sometimes in other part of application when map is forced to clear and move camera.
This error only happens on page where I have to do a lot of work on map.
In other pages there is no problem. When I want to make this error again it does not come up.

My second problem is that when user plays with map a lot the size of data in memory grows up. What might be the way to clear it? I know that when I use

```
this.map.setVisible(false);
```

it saves map state in the background and only hides map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already found a solution to first problem. I came up with idea that markerCluster is the best solution, cause app crash might have been connected with markers overloading map during adding markers. MarkerCluster only loads few markers which are referencing others (Google Maps Native plugin).